# Why does INDIRECT() not work with name references?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect

As far as my understanding goes, if you have value 5 in H4, there are two ways to reference that cell that both work:

```
=H4
```

and

```
=INDIRECT("H4")
```

I can't figure out a way to make this work with name references though. For example, if I have some data I'd like to calculate the sum of, I can do this:

```
=SUM(Main!SomeData)
```

but the other method...

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("Main!SomeData"))
```

suddenly does NOT work, and I get a `#REF` error. I need to be able to use a named range in my `INDIRECT()` for something more complex, but I can't wrap my head around why it won't work like this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your formula will work if `Main` is the name of the **workbook** *(not the worksheet)* in which the formula resides:

[image]

If the formula resides in a different workbook, *(say Book1.xlsx)*, then  both should be open for the formula to work.